# How to add custom object tabs in lightning experience?

Tags: lightning-experience

We are not able to see the custom object tabs in the navigation menu in lightning.How to add custom object tabs in lightning experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup Home>Apps>App Manager
There is a drop down arrow to the right of each app, click edit.  You can then select the object you would like to add tabs for each app.